# How to partition records into groups defined by the total sum of a certain column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

**For example**, consider the following data:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (Id INT, Value INT)
INSERT INTO @data VALUES
(0,1),
(1,2),
(2,3),
(3,1),
(4,1),
(5,1)
```

I want to transform this data into the following:

```
Id  Value  Group
0   1      0
1   2      0
2   3      1
3   1      2
4   1      2
5   1      2
```

When inspecting the items in the order of their Ids we compute the total running sum of `Value`. When it reaches 3 we say the group is complete and start a new group and a new total running sum. This way the given data produces 3 groups (when inspected in the specific order, of course).

Can I compute the `Group` in Sql Server 2012?

Please, note that this example is somewhat contrived. The real numbers are larger and there are many of them. The sum threshold may as well be a BIGINT.

Comment: @RyanVincent: Is very simple to compute these groups. See my solution.

Comment: Just saying...  I wish everyone posted the @table as you did.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  Id, 
        [Value],
        [Value] as sum_val, 
        0 as grp
FROM @data
WHERE Id = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT  d.id,
        d.[Value], 
        CASE WHEN LAG(sum_val,0,0) OVER (ORDER BY c.Id) = 3 OR d.[Value] = 3 THEN d.[Value] ELSE sum_val+c.[Value] END, 
        CASE WHEN LAG(sum_val,0,0) OVER (ORDER BY c.Id) = 3 OR d.[Value] = 3 THEN grp+1 ELSE grp END
FROM @data d
INNER JOIN cte c
    ON d.Id = c.Id+1
)

SELECT  id,
        [Value],
        grp
FROM cte
```

Will give you:

```
id  Value   grp
0   1       0
1   2       0
2   3       1
3   1       2
4   1       2
5   1       2
```

If add

```
(6,2),
(7,0),
(8,1),
(9,3)
```

To `@data` table, output will be:

```
id  Value   grp
0   1       0
1   2       0
2   3       1
3   1       2
4   1       2
5   1       2
6   2       3
7   0       3
8   1       3
9   3       4
```

I guess the problem will occurs if you pass f.e. `(0,2),(1,2)`, how to count group in this situation?